# How to create local GTK3 settings?

Tags: gnome, gtk3

I have changed gtk-main.css of my current theme to get different tooltip colors. But this applies to all users. Is there a way to create local GTK3 settings just for a specific user?

TIA
Kibu

Comment: Use ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini as well as ~/.themes (and ~/.icons)

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of your theme in `~/.themes`, e.g. for the Ambiance theme

```
cp -r /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/ ~/.themes
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.themes
```

And customize `~/.themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css`

Start `gnome-tweak-tool` and select your theme.